# Python - format csv data for Binary Classifier

Tags: python, csv, classification

I have some `csv` data formatted like so:

```
headers = [artist_list, song_list, lyrics_track, lyrics_artist, lyrics]`,
```

and this snippet:

```
with open('lyrics.tsv', "rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        print 'line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line)
```

prints:

```
(...)

line[808] = ['Pearl Jam', 'Wishlist', 'Wishlist', 'Pearl Jam', "I wish I was a neutron bomb\nfor once I could go off\nI wish I was a sacrifice\nbut somehow still lived on\nI wish I was a sentimental\nornament you hung on\nthe Christmas tree, I wish I was\nthe star that went on top\nI wish I was the evidence\nI wish I was the grounds\nfor fifty million hands upraised and opened toward the sky\nI wish I was a sailor with\nsomeone who waited for me\nI wish I was as fortunate\nas fortunate as me\nI wish I was a messenger\nand all the news was good\nI wish I was the full moon shining\noff a Camaro's hood\nI wish I was an alien\nat home behind the sun\nI wish I was the souvenir\nyou kept your house key on\nI wish I was the pedal break\nthat you depended on\nI wish I was the verb to trust\nand never let you down\nI wish I was a radio song\nthe one that you turned up\nI wish ..."]
```

now I would like to use the data for classification, keeping only the `lyrics` for all lines and adding a column for a binary value (always the same, `0`), so data is transformed into:

```
 lyrics                                                   type

 (...)                                                   (...)

 I wish I was a neutron bomb\nfor once I could go off..    0
```

how can I do this starting from the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this might work (assuming your data is a in a dataframe named lyrics_df):

```
lyrics_df['type']=0
```

Comment: it is not. how do I convert it to such a dataframe? could you please expand on your answer?

Comment: If your raw data is in a csv format, you could just use pandas in-build [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function. In this case, 'lyrics_df = pd.read_csv('lyrics.tsv')' should work.